# Function imported from dependency not found, requires library(dependency)

Tags: r, dependencies, devtools

I am trying to create an R package that uses functions from another package (*gamlss.tr*).

The function I need from the dependency is `gamlss.dist::TF` (*gamlss.dist* is loaded alongside *gamlss.tr*), but it is referenced in my code as simply `TF` within a call to `gamlss.tr::gen.trun`.

When I load *gamlss.tr* manually with `library()`, this works. However, when I rely on the functions of the dependency automatically being imported by my package through `@import`, I get an "object not found" error as soon as `TF` is accessed.

My attempt to be more explicit and reference the function I need as `gamlss.dist::TF` resulted in a different error ("unexpected '::'").

Any tips on how to use this function in my package would be much appreciated!

---

The code below reproduces the problem if incorporated into a clean R package (as done in [this .zip](https://github.com/decso17/dec2017/archive/master.zip)), built and loaded with `document("/path/to/package")`:

```
#' @import gamlss gamlss.tr gamlss.dist
NULL

#' Use GAMLSS
#'
#' Generate a truncated distribution and use it.
#' @export

use_gamlss <- function() {
  print("gen.trun():")

  gamlss.tr::gen.trun(par=0,family=TF)
    #Error in inherits(object, "gamlss.family") : object 'TF' not found
  #gamlss.tr::gen.trun(par=0,family=gamlss.dist::TF)
    #Error in parse(text = fname) : <text>:1:1: unexpected '::'
  y = rTFtr(1000,mu=10,sigma=5, nu=5)

  print("trun():")

  truncated_dist = gamlss.tr::trun(par=0,family=TF, local=TRUE)
  model = gamlss(y~1, family=truncated_dist)
  print(model)
}
```

`use_gamlss()` will only start working once a user calls `library(gamlss.tr)`.

Comment: Is your package on github?

Comment: Hi Dason, sure: https://github.com/decso17/dec2017

Comment: You need the package to the Imports section of your DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: I'd recommend using `devtools`, `devtools::use_package` will take care of all of this for you.

Comment: My apologies for forgetting to do so in the example. I tried this with my original code, but it does not solve this issue sadly. I've updated the repository to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This is due to bad design of `gamlss.tr` in particular the `trun.x` functions (they take character vectors instead of family objects / they evaluate everything in the function environment instead of the calling environment).

To work around this, you have to make sure that `gamlss.distr` is in the search path of the execution environment of `gamlss.tr` functions (This is why `#@ import`-ing it in your package does not help: it would need to be `#' @import`-ed in `gamlss.tr`).

This can be achieved by adding it to `Depends:` of your package.

If you want to avoid that attaching your package also attaches `gamlss.distr`, you could also add the following at the top of `use_gamlss`:

```
  nsname <-"gamlss.dist"
  attname <- paste0("package:", nsname)
  if (!(attname %in% search())) {
    attachNamespace(nsname)
    on.exit(detach(attname, character.only = TRUE))
  }
```

This would temporarily attach `gamlss.dist` if it is not attached already.

You can read more on namespaces in R in [Hadley Wickham's "Advanced R"](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/environments.html#namespaces)